# QGIS 2.14 LTR Merge Raster repeatedly fails

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, merge

I recently installed QGIS 2.14 LTR and I am seeing what it can do.  I have repeatedly tried to merge 2 rasters (USGS 1/3 arc second DEM's) in both an ESRI grid format and a GeoTIFF format and each time Merge fails.  Here are the diagnostics:

```
gdal_merge.bat -of GTiff -o C:/Users/Steve/Documents/QGIS/Projects/Garmin/Data/GDD/grdn40-41w106.tif C:\Users\Steve\Documents\QGIS\Projects\Garmin\Data\GDD\grdn40w106.tif C:\Users\Steve\Documents\QGIS\Projects\Garmin\Data\GDD\grdn41w106.tif

Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.14\bin\gdal_merge.py", line 540, in 
sys.exit(main()) 
File "C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.14\bin\gdal_merge.py", line 526, in main 
fi.copy_into( t_fh, band, band, nodata ) 
File "C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.14\bin\gdal_merge.py", line 270, in copy_into 
nodata_arg ) 
File "C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.14\bin\gdal_merge.py", line 77, in raster_copy 
m_band ) 
File "C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.14\bin\gdal_merge.py", line 128, in raster_copy_with_mask 
data_dst = t_band.ReadAsArray( t_xoff, t_yoff, t_xsize, t_ysize ) 
File "C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py", line 2320, in ReadAsArray 
callback_data = callback_data) 
File "C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal_array.py", line 330, in BandReadAsArray 
buf_obj = numpy.empty([buf_ysize,buf_xsize], dtype = typecode) 
MemoryError
```

AND using ESRI grids:

```
gdal_merge.bat -of GTiff -o C:/Users/Steve/Documents/QGIS/Projects/Garmin/Data/GDD/grdn40-41w106.tif C:\Users\Steve\Documents\DataGIS\USGS\DEM_1_3as\n40w106\grdn40w106_13\w001001.adF  C:\Users\Steve\Documents\DataGIS\USGS\DEM_1_3as\n41w106\grdn41w106_13\w001001.adf

Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.14\bin\gdal_merge.py", line 540, in 
sys.exit(main()) 
File "C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.14\bin\gdal_merge.py", line 526, in main 
fi.copy_into( t_fh, band, band, nodata ) 
File "C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.14\bin\gdal_merge.py", line 270, in copy_into 
nodata_arg ) 
File "C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.14\bin\gdal_merge.py", line 77, in raster_copy 
m_band ) 
File "C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.14\bin\gdal_merge.py", line 128, in raster_copy_with_mask 
data_dst = t_band.ReadAsArray( t_xoff, t_yoff, t_xsize, t_ysize ) 
File "C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py", line 2320, in ReadAsArray 
callback_data = callback_data) 
File "C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal_array.py", line 330, in BandReadAsArray 
buf_obj = numpy.empty([buf_ysize,buf_xsize], dtype = typecode) 
MemoryError
```

Other GDAL algorithms (hillshade, contour) that I tried work OK but QGIS does not seem able to merge 2 rasters.

Comment: how big are the input files? it looks like it's running out of memory

Comment: 2 x 446 MB GeoTIFFs.  Note my answer below, that by installing QGIS 2.18.9 64 bit merge rasters is working OK now. I am feeling better about QGIS now as I have moved a few more steps forward.

Answer (score 1):

By installing QGIS 2.18.9 64 bit Merge is now working.